# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{...} to activity {....FacebookSignUp}: java.lang.NullPointerException:

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, null-pointer

In the Google Play Console pre-launch report, I the "STABILITY" section, I have this error that I need to fix:

Galaxy S9

**Test ID:** 2
**Test Duration:** 300 seconds
**Model Name:** Galaxy S9
**Manufacturer:** Samsung
**Android Version:** Android 8.0
**Locale:** es_US
**Screen Size:** 1080 × 2220
**Screen Density (dpi):** 480
**RAM:** 4096 MB
**OpenGL ES Version:** 3.2
**Native Platform:** armeabi-v7a
**CPU Make:** Qualcomm
**CPU Model:** SDM845

```
Issue: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=32665, result=0, data=null} to activity {[...].FacebookSignUp}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: [...], PID: 25180
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=32665, result=0, data=null} to activity {[...].FacebookSignUp}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4489)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4532)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1752)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.easy.facebook.android.facebook.FBLoginManager.loginSuccess(FBLoginManager.java:99)
    at [...].FacebookSignUp.onActivityResult(FacebookSignUp.java:187)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7539)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4485)
    ... 9 more
```

I suspect that this problem might be happening because my Facebook library is too old. In my `app/build.gradle` I am using this Facebook library:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
```

I am sure it is very old and most likely deprecated in many ways. It still works though, but it might be the cause of this error that I see. Also, I am using this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation files('libs/easyfacebookandroidsdk_2.3.jar')
    ....
}
```

That Facebook library must be the cause. Any ideas about fixing that `NullPointerException` that I see in the error? I guess the best should be for me to upgrade those very old Facebook libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not Facebook. After examining the logs, the real problem was this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
Process: [package name], PID: 5893
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient;
    at com.couponclub.Util.Util$1.run(Util.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.couponclub.Util.Util$1.run(Util.java:235) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/[package name]-3cwAF4cAFytf561aNx4V2Q==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The solution was to go include the following line inside of the `<application>` section of my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

This is explained at https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p.